# Rule to demote content from frontpage without advising subscribers

Tags: rules, notifications

I have rules that demotes content nodes from frontpage based on different criteria. They use a shared component to set data value

```
Parameter: Data: [node:promote], Value: false
```

Problem is that this triggers a mail to all subscribers of node updates.
How can I prevent that?

When manually editing a node, there is a "Send subscriptions notifications" that I can uncheck, but I can't seem to find that option in Rules.

EDIT:
I have this rule:

```
{ "rules_demote_old_articles" : {
    "LABEL" : "Demote old articles",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "story" : "story" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_demote_node",
          "date" : "+4 weeks",
          "identifier" : "Demote article [node:nid].",
          "param_node" : [ "node" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the corresponding copmponent:

```
{ "rules_demote_node" : {
    "LABEL" : "Demote node",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:promote" ], "value" : 0 } } ]
  }
}
```

Where do I unset the send_subscriptions_notifications to avoid sending out subscription mails?

Comment: At least for Fields in Rules ... you need to add a validation check to your rule of the form `node or bundle has Field WHATEVER` prior to trying to `set field send_subscriptions_notifications = FALSE` in the rule. I'm not sure if this is true for `options` of content types.

Comment: That makes no sense to me, can you take it to my noob level?
I have edited the question to make my situation clearer.

Comment: You're trying to demote something, but there is a checkbox that you apparently don't know how to set in Rules (or see the Rules UI at all). I suspect it *could* be related to this: https://drupalcommerce.org/faq/rules-field-data-selection

You may need to `validate` in Rules the option is present in the Entity before Rules will let you set it. Your exported Rules has nothing like: `{ "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_first_published_date" } },` ... this is my best guess, having had the similar (how do I set this thing I cant _see_ in Rules).

Comment: How would checking the existence of field "field_first_published_date" help me unsetting the "send_subscriptions_notification"? Is "send_subscriptions_notification" even a field on a (story) node ?

Comment: I was commenting or suggesting you try to validate the `item` (option, field, whatever) exists using Rules on the `Entity` you want to do work on -- because Rules doesn't or can't inspect all the properties it can modify out of the box. You typically need to "check the field" exists to modify a field -- I assume the same is true for additional node options. Good luck on your project.

Comment: As far as i can figure out, the problem is in the component "Demote node" that is run 4 weeks after the rule has fired. How can adding a check in the rule influence on what is available to the component. This really puzzles me.

Comment: "How can adding a check in the rule influence on what is available to the component". EXACTLY. That's a caveat or issue with Rules -- sometimes you need to do this to make the item available to the component. It's a known issue with the Rules module. If you don't know this already and aren't willing to do research or experiment with the module then good luck.

Comment: Dont get upset, I AM researching all I can, but even when I put a check in the rule for the existence of field_first_published_date AND send_subscriptions_notifications, none of them appear in the components data selector dropdown as node:xxx